# php validation: no spaces in string

Tags: php, html, wordpress, validation

I'm setting up a custom php form validation used in conjunction with wordpress contact form 7 plugin, I've set up a validation rule as the text field, I only want people to type 1 word (i.e. no spaces) and for that one word to begin with the letter `s`.
The letter `s` validation works just fine but while this works, the no spaces (one word) validation doesn't seem to be working?
php:

```
if($name == 'FirstField') {
        $FirstField = $_POST['FirstField'];

        if($FirstField != '') {
            if (!preg_match("/(^[^s]|\s)/i",$FirstField)){
                $result['valid'] = true;
            } else {
                $result['valid'] = false;
                $result['reason'][$name] = 'Invalid Entry.';
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I tested your regex it seems to do what you want. Can you give an example of a value that does not give your expected result?

Comment: As a side note, you can always test your regular expressions here...   http://rubular.com/r/CnxN4oJub2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test:

> if($name == 'FirstField') {
>           $FirstField = $_POST['FirstField'];
>
> ```
>     if($FirstField != '') {
>         if (!preg_match("/(^[^s]|\+s)/i",$FirstField)){
>             $result['valid'] = true;
>         } else {
>             $result['valid'] = false;
>             $result['reason'][$name] = 'Invalid Entry.';
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

UPDATED:

> ```
> if($name == 'FirstField') { $FirstField = $_POST['FirstField'];
>
>     if($FirstField != '' && isset($FirstField) ) {
>         $FirstField = explode(' ', $FirstField); //Get only first word
>         if (!preg_match("/(^[^s]|\+s)/i",$FirstField[0])){
>             $result['valid'] = true;
>         } else {
>             $result['valid'] = false;
>             $result['reason'][$name] = 'Invalid Entry.';
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

***FIXED ERROR last:***

***replace:***

> if($FirstField != '' && isset($FirstField)

***by:***

> if($FirstField != '' && isset($FirstField) )

I hope help you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, still doesn't seem to be working though. the s validation is working fine, the no spaces one though, still isn't :(

Comment: still no luck with that, there's a syntax error in there too, missing a closing bracket ;) thanks for your help though…just still no luck :(

Comment: if($FirstField != '' && isset($FirstField) ) ... The problem is closet ")" the condition statement "if" ;-)

Comment: even with the syntax correction is still doesn't seem to work, again the s validation is still working, the spaces one is still a no go though, I can't figure it out :(

Comment: but do not worry anyway with denial "!" in condition and works. My is working in my test site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43547/discussion-between-josecarlos-and-user1374796)

Comment: still doesn't seem to work, the `s` validation is fine, but an `s` word with a space is still getting through :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
preg_match("/^s[a-z]*$/i", $FirstField)
```

Assuming that your word consists of only letters.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 's' (case insensitive), no spaces: `preg_match('/^s[^ ]*$/i', $string)`

Starting with 's' (case insensitive), no white-space (spaces, tabs, etc): `preg_match('/^s\S*$/i', $string)`

**edit**

You might also be interested in `\w`, which matches "word characters" (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _): `preg_match('/^s\w*$/i', $string)`